# Html code is not recognised when used with Php

Tags: php, html

I get below output on the browser:

```
class="text"> class="text"> class="text"> class="text"> class="text">
```

Issue is with the line below:

```
<tr <?php=($cnt%2?'':'bgcolor="#EAEBEE"')?> class="text">
```

html code after end tag of PHP '?>' is not recognized as Html

Let me know if more code is required to debug.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have echo after <?php  ??. Otherwise you can use <?=  . My advice is that you use a proper IDE.  It'll help identify little syntax errors like this

Comment: Use <?= in replace of <?php=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for a shorthand `<?php echo` tag is this: `<?=`

Try this:

```
<tr <?=($cnt%2?'':'bgcolor="#EAEBEE"')?> class="text">
```

Comment: bgcolor isn't a CSS rule

Comment: @Blaise the style from my table is gone. Replacing <?php to <? works well.

Comment: That was the solution?

Comment: @Devon Oh yeah. :)

Comment: @Blaise Yes, replacing <?php to <? worked. I wasn't able to use your code, I tried to even replace bgcolor with background-color

Comment: To be honest, I think you should consider removing this answer as it misleads one to believe that the ternary operator in the OP is a problem.

Comment: @Devon, I can remove it if that would be helpful... Would it be better to edit it?